# Android Volley caching

Tags: android-volley

I'm testing Volley and have a question to the volley caching behaviour..

my Code:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this); 
    final String url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/test.php";

    // prepare the Request
    JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {   
                            // display response     
                Log.d("Response", response.toString());
            }
        }, 
        new Response.ErrorListener() 
        {
             @Override
             public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {            
                Log.d("Error.Response", "test");
           }
        }
    );

    // add it to the RequestQueue   
    queue.add(getRequest);
```

I get this response from the server: {"a":"111","b":"222"}

so far everything ok..

but when i change the data on the server e.g. : {"a":"111","b":"333"} and start the app again, volley get the same response like before.. {"a":"111","b":"222"}.

i think voley caches the old request.. how can i change this? i want every time actual data from the server..

**EDIT:

I solved the "stupid" Problem..

Just add: header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
in the php file..**

Comment: You can write and mark that as an answer, would be helpful for others. :)

Answer (score 2):

befor adding a getReuest in queue  just add a single line

```
queue.getCache().clear();
```

by using this you can clear the cache of volley cache and every time you get the responce what ever is coming from server. you can do this like this

```
 RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this); 
  final String url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/test.php";

// prepare the Request 
JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() 
    { 
        @Override 
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {   
                        // display response      
            Log.d("Response", response.toString());
        } 
    },  
    new Response.ErrorListener() 
    { 
         @Override 
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {            
            Log.d("Error.Response", "test");
       } 
    } 
); 
//to clear the cache 
queue.getCache().clear();

// add it to the RequestQueue    
queue.add(getRequest);
```